# Counting the same nearest values in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given this array:

`[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4]`

How can I efficently count the nearest same elements in array, the result I would expect is:

```
1 => 2,
2 => 1,
1 => 3,
2 => 1,
3 => 1,
4 => 3,
6 => 1,
4 => 2
```

I don't know how to formulate correctly the question but I think the example is pretty clear.

I tried using reduce to make more compact and elegant but I always get a value with total number of same value in array.

```
let result = testArray.reduce((allValues, value) => {
      if(value in allValues){
        allValues[value]++;
      } else {
        allValues[value] = 1;
      }

      return allValues;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Please post the code of your attempt.

Comment: @Bergi I added the code I tried to use, but probably I'm on the wrong path..

Comment: You cannot return an object, as a value can only be used once as a key. What result format do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the last element and if equal, increment count, if not push a new object to the result set.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4],
    count = array.reduce((r, a, i, aa) => {
        if (aa[i - 1] === a) {
            r[r.length - 1].count++;
        } else {
            r.push({ value: a, count: 1 });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` and a `hash table` - see demo below:

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4];

var result = array.reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c,i){
    hash[c] = (hash[c] || 0) + 1;
    if(hash.prev && (hash.prev !== c || i == array.length - 1)) {
      let obj= {}; 
      obj[hash.prev] = hash[hash.prev];
      delete hash[hash.prev];
      p.push(obj);
    }
    hash.prev = c;
    return p;
  }
}(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) is a nice function, it does have some compatibility issues.

Here is a solution using old school for loops:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4];
var results = [];
for (var indexA = 0; indexA < arr.length; indexA++) {
    var a = arr[indexA];
    if (results.length > 0) {
        if (a == results[results.length - 1]["value"]) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    var r = { value: a, index: indexA, count: 0 };
    for (var indexB = indexA; indexB < arr.length; indexB++) {
        var b = arr[indexB];
        if (a != b) {
            break;
        }
        r.count++;
    }
    results.push(r);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Compatibility issues? With what?

Comment: @Bergi IE 9 and below primarily. You can see the table at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) under `Browser compatibility`. It's by no means critical, but in business-to-business or if catering to a clientele with older software it can be relevant.

Comment: @Bergi W3Counter has a nice diagram of current Internet Explorer trends here: [w3counter.com/trends](https://www.w3counter.com/trends#graph2)

Comment: IE9 *does* support it, and IE8 is irrelevant today. If you care about them, you should simply polyfill `reduce`, no need to adapt your coding style.

Answer (score 0):

The posted solutions are fine but as noted by @Emil S. Jørgensen there might be compatibility issues using Array.reduce. Also, the suggested old school solution by @Emil S. Jørgensen uses two loops. If you want to have a slightly more efficient,simple and straightforward solution which will work in all browsers then use:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4];
var result = [];

var current = arr[0];
var count = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] === current)
    {
        count+= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[current] = count;
        result.push(newObj);
        current = arr[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}

console.log(result); //prints the solution
```